# Check an address to see if there is any video stream on it or not

Tags: stream, ffmpeg, udp, libavcodec, libavformat

I want to read a video stream from a UDP address using libavcodec functions. To do so, I use the following code:

```
 char *url = "udp://127.0.0.1:1000";
 AVFormatContext *oc = NULL;
 avformat_open_input(&oc, url, NULL , NULL);
```

If we run this code, then function "avformat_open_input" starts listening on the given UDP address, and it looks like the program is halted if there is no video stream at the given UDP address.

Now, I want to write a code to first check the given UDP address quickly to see whether there is any data on it or not, if there is no data then the program should neglect running "avformat_open_input", otherwise it should run this function so that I can avoid the halting situation.

Any idea how I can do this? Thanks!

Comment: You have to realize that if the media stream does not saturate your bandwidth, there will always be moments in time when there is "nothing to be read" from the socket, so checking for this condition as quickly as possible will certainly not be reliable.

Comment: @SirDarius : thanks, but how I can avoid "avformat_open_input" listening forever on the given address?

Comment: Not too sure about this, but there might be an option allowing to specify read timeout (ref http://ffmpeg.org/pipermail/ffmpeg-devel/2012-August/129625.html)

Comment: @Blue Sky did you found anything for avoiding "avformat_open_input" forever listening